# Filter lines using grep -v

Tags: grep

I am trying to filter out lines that don't contain the file names as below using the following command but I am not sure why line with permission denied keeps coming in my result.  It should be gone when I have used `grep -v "total|denied"`.

```
wc -l *.*   | egrep  -v "total|denied"  | sort -nr -k1,1

wc: host.save: Permission denied
33301 apache-maven-3.5.3-bin.tar.gz
14149 jenkins-cli.jar
 240 examples.desktop
  19 list.py
  19 interview_GL.sh
  17 lines.txt
   7 number.py
```

Comment: but I am filtering it out in grep

Comment: The problem is that grep is taking stdout as its input, whereas the 'Permission denied' output is going to stderr, which grep does not take as input by default.

Comment: Thanks Christopher, that made Perfect sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only stdout gets passed to the pipe into grep but those error messages are on stderr

You can either forward stderr to /dev/null or send them to stdout aswell

Send errors to /dev/null:

```
wc -l * 2>/dev/null
```

Redirect errors to stdout:

```
wc -l * 2>&1 | grep -v dir
```

Comment: Thanks Sven, I get it.

Answer (score 1):

You obviously aren't allowed to read `host.save` file's contents, therefore the error coming from the first command.

Have you tried muting the errors instead?

```
wc -l *.* 2>/dev/null | egrep  -v "total|denied"  | sort -nr -k1,1
```